# Leetcode Add Two Numbers in java?

Tags: java, algorithm

The Leetcode question:leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

> (Reference:Leetcode) You are given two linked lists representing two non-negative numbers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.
>   Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
>   Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8

My code does not work, but I think it is almost correct. What is the problem with my code?

```
  /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
int m = 0;
        int next=0;
        int recent=0;
        ListNode head = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode temp =head;
        while (l1 != null && l2 != null) {
            if (l1.val + l2.val < 10) {
                m = l1.val + l2.val;
                next=0;
            }else{
                m = (l1.val + l2.val)%10;
                next=1;
            }

            temp.next=new ListNode(m+recent);

            recent=next;
            temp=temp.next;
            l1 = l1.next;
            l2 = l2.next;

        }
        if(l1 != null){
            temp.next=new ListNode(l1.next.val+recent);
        }
        if(l2!= null){
            temp.next=new ListNode(l2.next.val+recent);
        }
        if(recent!=0){
            temp.next=new ListNode(recent);
        }

        System.out.print(head.next.val);
        return head;
    }



}
```

The Leetcode question:leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

My code does not work, but I think it is almost correct. What is the problem with my code?

Comment: Need a more specific question. How does it not work? What does it do and what should it do?

Comment: @jb.I add more description

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, `suppose l1 is shorter than l2 by more than 1,` you did not do the rest thing outside loop correctly.

```
Because you only allocate one more node after you are outside loop.
```

Since you've got most things right, hopefully noticing this would help you out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code are

1. Incomplete code
2. Incorrect update of node value

> **Node value is 10** when recent = 1, m = 9 or l1.next.val = 9 or
>   l2.next.val = 9

3. Fail to handle l1 or l2 in if-statement when remaining of l1 or l2 is at least 2 digits long

> Failure to handle l1 = 9->9->9->1 and l2 = 1

4. Incorrect use of node value in if-statement

> Why ignore l2.val in **temp.next=new ListNode(l2.next.val+recent);** ?